# Customize Asp.net Identity with Int Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to customize Asp.net Identity with `Int` as primary key. I have already implemented the code to change `string` key to `int` key.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace NewAsp.netAuth.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser :  IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
    }

    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
    int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Also I want users use their email address to login to my website instead of their username, so I change `AccountViewModels.cs`. by registering, entered Email address will be saved in `Username` column instead of `Email` column.

Here is my code:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "EMail Adress")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email Adress")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

and this :

```
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser,int> userManager)
{
            UserManager = userManager;
            var userValidator = UserManager.UserValidator as UserValidator<ApplicationUser,int>;
            userValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
        }
```

In this situation I have some question:

1. How can I remove `Email`, `EmailConfirmed, PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberConfirmed, TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEndDateUtc,` and... columns.
2. How can I add some new columns like `Name, Family`, ...
3. How can I completly remove the `AspNetUserClaims` table
4. Is it possible to remove `AspNetUserRoles` table and in `AspNetUsers` table and add a foreign key from `AspNetRoles` table ?

I read lots of tutorials but could not find any good solution

- [Implementing ASP.NET Identity](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx)
- [A simple implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-simple-implementation-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace default data access implementation.

First, you create your own User class. It will have integer primary key, email as username, and any custom fields you want.

```
class User : IUser<int>
{
   public int Id
   { get; set; }

   public string Name
   { get; set; }

   public string Email
   { get; set; }

   public string PasswordHash
   { get; set; }

   public string SecurityStamp
   { get; set; }

   // other fields here

   string IUser<int>.UserName
   {
      get { return Email; }
      set { Email = value; }
   }
}
```

Then you implement UserStore interfaces. You may need to implement other interfaces as well.

```
class CustomUserStore: 
    IUserStore<User, int>,
    IUserPasswordStore<User, int>,
    IUserSecurityStampStore<User, int>
{
    AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext();

    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
    {
        return context.Users.FindAsync(userId);
    }

    public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        return context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == userName);
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(User user)
    {
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(User user)
    {
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash != null);
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.PasswordHash);
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<string> GetSecurityStampAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(user.SecurityStamp);
    }

    public Task SetSecurityStampAsync(User user, string stamp)
    {
        user.SecurityStamp = stamp;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Pass new UserStore implementation to UserManager:

```
class CustomUserManager : UserManager<User, int>
{
    public CustomUserManager()
        : base(new CustomUserStore())
    {

    }
}
```

This will get you started.